# Experimental evidence for Z boson coupling to right handed fermions

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

I do have a question about electro-weak interactions.

I know the Z boson is an admixture of two fields, one that couples only to the left-handed part of the fermions (the neutral field introduced to make SU(2) a local symmetry) and one that couples to both  left and right handed components of the fermions (the field introduced to make U(1) a local symmetry). My question is, what is the experimental evidence telling us that the Z boson actually couples to both left and right handed components?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For example the width of the Z which has been measured to $0.1\%$ level of accuracy. Should only right- or left-handed fermions coupled to Z the change in Z would be much larger than that.m

Answer (score 3):

In addition to TwoBs' comments, in the 90s, there had been many collisions at SLAC (USA) with polarized electron/positron beams of the SLC collider running at the $Z$ pole. Therefore, the right handed component of the electroweak interaction has been extensively tested.
See the wikipage:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAC_National_Accelerator_Laboratory